# How to keep labels on tuple types when destructuring them

Tags: typescript

With the following code

```
type labels = [a: number, b: string]
type spread = [...labels]
type combined = [c: boolean, ...labels]
```

`spread` keeps the labels `a` and `b`, but when combining these into `combined` type, type checking gives an error saying all tuple type members must all have names or do not have names. This means in the second case, the destructuring also erases the labels `a` and `b`, making it equivalent to `c: boolean, number, string`.

How can the combined type be done properly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: name the tuple before spreading it

```
type labels = [a: number, b: string]
type spread = [...labels]
type combined = [c: boolean, ...labels:labels]
```

Thanks to support from the Typescript discord channel.